# How do I target and change the style of a different element when I click a button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I target a different react element inside the same component when I click on a button and how can this work when I reuse the component several times in my App.js?

I have created a react component that has a div and a button. By default, I made the div hidden by creating a "hidden" CSS style and giving the div the class "hidden". Now what I want to achieve is that when I click the button, it will call a function that will make the div become visible by removing the hidden class from it's classList. My react component was created with class and I am binding the "this" keyword in constructor.

Now I have gone ahead to call the re-usable component above in four places in my App.js. On the first instance of the component, when I click the button, the div becomes visible as expected, but in other instances, when I click the buttons, the other corresponding divs do not become visible as expected per component instance. So my button click only affect the first instance of my react component while the remaining do not act accordingly.

This is the function I am calling by clicking the button

```
handleFinish() {
        console.log("CLickedddd");
        const editBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".ResetButton");
        for (let i = 0; i < editBtn.length; i++) {
          editBtn[i].classList.remove("hidden");
        }
```

This is the button and div:

```
<button id="finish" onClick={this.handleFinish}>
            Finish
          </button>
          <div style={{height: 300, width: 300, backgroundColor: "red"}} class="hidden">
            
          </div>
```

Comment: why dont you store the visibility in your component's state?

Comment: did our answers help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a state variable to control your div's visibility.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { hidden: false };
  }

  handleFinish = () => {
    console.log("CLickedddd");
    this.setState({ hidden: !this.state.hidden });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button id="finish" onClick={this.handleFinish}>
          Finish
        </button>
        <div
          style={{ height: 300, width: 300, backgroundColor: "red" }}
          className={this.state.hidden ? "hidden" : ""}
        ></div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-dust-dtozhw?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This works like magic!. I spent all of yesterday on this without solving it. Thank you very very much!
Before you answered, I also solved the issue by using CreateRef API. But this your solution is way way simpler and better, besides there is also that caution of avoiding Refs when possible. Thanks again @Apostolos.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
export default function App() {
  const handleFinish = () => {
    const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    myDiv.classList.remove("hidden");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button id="finish" onClick={handleFinish}>
        Finish
      </button>
      <div
        id="myDiv"
        style={{ height: 300, width: 300, backgroundColor: "red" }}
        className="hidden"
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can assign an id or className to the targeted div, and on the `onClick` handle you could remove the class from the div.

Here, is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-williams-d5odtr?file=/src/App.js:24-457).

But, better than this if you want to do more like a react way, you could create a state for this div visibility and just update the state to make that div visible. Like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [divVisibility, setDivVisibility] = useState(false);

  const handleFinish = () => {
    setDivVisibility(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button id="finish" onClick={handleFinish}>
        Finish
      </button>
      <div
        id="myDiv"
        style={{ height: 300, width: 300, backgroundColor: "red" }}
        className={divVisibility ? "" : "hidden"}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And, here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-answer-64e2nn) for it.

**#PS**: I have used CSS for `hidden` class to make it actually display none. and I hope you have used something similar CSS or you have used the framework that provide this class.

Comment: Hi Saroj, I appreciate your time on this. The issue is that this works when you are using that component only once. If you duplicate the component that has the button and div and render the duplicated in a single page, it won't work because Js only recognizes one div per DOM.
See the Code sandbox for example of how your solution works when implemented on my intended situation: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-black-hsu6e7?file=/src/App.js:528-541

Comment: Also, your second solution works great. But the problem now is, how do I replicate this if I am using a Class component instead of the functional component that you used. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Update: @Apostolos has solved this using class. I appreciate you and if there is a different approach you come up with, kindly share too. Thanks a lot.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72781192/14600144